# Не получается отделить кавычки от параметра в cmd

Tags: cmd, bat

Есть параметр, переданный в cmd в формате `"ARG=CUSTOM_SOURCE,SOURCE=C:\Folder\OtherFolder\SourceFiles"`. 
Для того, чтобы выделить `ARG` и `SOURCE` с их значениями, надо преобразовать параметр в формат `ARG=CUSTOM_SOURCE,SOURCE=C:\Folder\OtherFolder\SourceFiles`

Код:

```
set test=%1
for /f "delims=" %%A in ("!test!") do set "test=%%~A"
echo test after process is "%test%"
rem output: ""ARG=CUSTOM_SOURCE,SOURCE=C:\Folder\OtherFolder\SourceFiles""
:nextVar
   for /F "tokens=1* delims=," %%a in ("%test%") do (
      set %%a
      set test=%%b
   )
if defined test goto nextVar

set test=%ARG%
```

Также пробовался такой вариант:

```
set test=%test:"=%
```

Результат тот же: `""ARG=CUSTOM_SOURCE,SOURCE=C:\Folder\OtherFolder\SourceFiles""`

В чем ошибка? Как убрать кавычки?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Получилось убрать кавычки таким образом:

```
set test=%1

:nextVar
   for /F "tokens=1* delims=," %%a in ("%test:"=%") do (
      set %%a
      set test=%%b
   )
if defined test goto nextVar

set test=%ARG%
```

Все равно осталось непонятным, почему `set test=%test:"=%`  не дал того же результата

Answer (score 1):

Если положение символов для удаления (в данном случае двойных кавычек) имеет определенный порядок - в начале и в конце. То может не заморачиваться, а просто удалить их? Вот пример для обрезки строки с краев по одному символу.

```
@set test="ARG=CUSTOM_SOURCE,SOURCE=C:\Folder\OtherFolder\SourceFiles"

@set test=%test:~1,-1%
@echo.%test%
```

Если же положение кавычек не определено, то нужно сделать так, как Вы и предложили - через обработку строки. Но есть нюанс, для обработки нужно включить режим обработки переменных через символ !
А затем отключить его.
Отсюда имеем следующий код.

```
@set test="ARG=CUSTOM_"""SOURCE,SOURCE=C":\Fo""lder\OtherFolder\SourceFiles"

@setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
@set test=!test:"=!
@setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
@echo %test%
```

Comment: Могут быть параметры без кавычек, для них не подойдет.  Нужно именно кавычки убрать.

Comment: Дополнил ответ.

Comment: У меня есть строка `setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion` в начале кода, как я поняла, все равно не помогало.

Comment: Так Вы же сами написали, что использовали переменную **"%test%"**, а следовало бы **"!test!"**

Comment: А вот это я, действительно упустила... Мне казалось, что set должен работать в любом случае, разве нет?

Comment: **setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion** для того и использовалось, чтобы избежать экранирования/деления строки кавычками при задании переменной командой **set**.  Именно это я и подразумевал в своем ответе.

Comment: Все, поняла Вас. Спасибо!